# Prevent users from reusing website source files (downloading is okay)

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE:**

Something's wrong with stackoverflow. It seems people couldn't read the first line of the question properly and they start preaching about "how websites can't be downloaded" which is not exactly the question. So here is the question in a more specific way:

How to get hosted **server**'s IP address (or any other information which is unique to the hosted server) using jQuery. Googling doesn't help much.

Now, please don't start with "getting client's IP address" or "this can't be done". I know this is nearly impossible; but if someone can get me close to the idea, that'll do.

**Oringinal Question:**

I know users can download the source files if they can see it in their browser. What I am trying to do is stop them from reusing it. Like checking IP of hosted server and redirecting to the original domain if the files are hosted in a different server.

Using PHP (or any server programs) won't do as the end user will be getting the final html/css/js files.

Basically, I don't want anyone to download and **host/reuse** website files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I don't want anyone to download website files and host/reuse it` this is not possible - unless you use some form of encryption on both server & client side.

Comment: anyone can save all files, that were downloaded by browser. You can get the licence, but it will not stop anybody. if you `don't want anyone to download website files and host/reuse it` - create sites on `localhost` and thay will always be `only yours`

Comment: Kindly read the question properly. "Downloading" is okay.
Won't there be anyway, like including a snippet within a js file that checks for hosted IP and redirect to original domain?

Comment: @dreamster even if you could, the person could just remove that code and still use it..

Comment: @RudieVisser ... which is okay. The codes aren't **special enough for the folks who are genius** enough to does that.
Thanks for your reply and reading the question properly. ;)

Comment: Sorry if this seems a stupid question, but why are you trying to do that? The basic story is the webserver sends everything to the client, and the end user can access all of it.

Comment: @BenHillier my company is about to present the final version of a website to the client, before getting the payment. It is **okay** for the client to download the files; but my company don't want them to host the files in their own server. So the boss asked me to check if this can be done.

Comment: Ok! I've added an answer about Obfuscating the Javascript below. I think that can help you!

Comment: thanks man, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is code, and can be obfuscated. This makes it so difficult to maintain that it's usually easier for the end user to re-write from scratch. Try Googling for "Javascript Obfuscator".

With HTML and CSS, it's pretty much open to the user. Not much you can do about that!

Comment: Obfuscating javascript helped me for now. I wrote a function to redirect the website to company website, if "today" is ahead of a certain date. Added that piece of code within other js functions used in the website and obfuscated them altogether.
Thanks again.

Comment: Cool! That should stop all but the most determined coders :-)

Answer (score 0):

**If you make website in PHP you will write some code that gets translated into end-html that user can view and download.** So your source file in PHP is unreachable for end-user. Like in Wordpress your code could be only few rows and end html could be hundreds of rows long because it reads data from a database and puts it into html.

If you write scripts in javascript you can not protect it from downloading and reusing that.

Answer (score -1):

This can't be helped. If the viewer can view your website he can download the front-end of the website.

If your worried about someone downloading your server-side scripts, you don't have to because server side cannot be downloaded through the front-end.